# How do you trigger a button's focus-within state when another button has been focused on or has a focused-within?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

View for reference

[image: 1]

I want the next inactive button to become active (turn bright red) when the (button) bank name has been selected or clicked.

I googled and found out there is a (blur) and (focus) event in angular

Answer (score 1):

You can disable and enable buttons via JavaScript:

```js
const normalButton = document.querySelector('.normal');
const disabledButton = document.querySelector('.disabled');

disabledButton.disabled = true;

normalButton.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    disabledButton.disabled = false;
})
```

```html
<p>Click on 'aaaa' button to enable the other button</p>
<button class="normal">aaaa</button>
<button class="disabled">bbbb</button>
```